# Hive table creation using OpenCsv SerDe

Tags: hive, opencsv

I created table using following command -

```
 create table cust(event int, pid int, REQ_FROM_IP int, REQ_CITY_ID int, REQ_STATE_ID int, REQ_COUNTRY_ID int, key String) 
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'                                                                                 
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (                                                                                                                        
  "separatorChar" = "|",                                                                                                                       
    "quoteChar"     = "'",                                                                                                                     
    "escapeChar"    = "\\"                                                                                                                     
 )STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

However the created table has all coloumns as String!

```
    desc cust;
    OK
event                   string                  from deserializer   
pid                     string                  from deserializer   
req_from_ip             string                  from deserializer   
req_city_id             string                  from deserializer   
req_state_id            string                  from deserializer   
req_country_id          string                  from deserializer   
key                     string                  from deserializer
```

Is it the SerDe messing with the datastructure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From perusing the source code, it looks like the OpenCSVSerde will always output string columns without regard for what types were actually specified in the HiveQL query.

A potential (not very pretty) workaround to this could be to use the OpenCSVSerde to format a staging table (the definition can be identical to what you currently have for `cust`, maybe call it `cust_staging`.  If your use case is that you're trying to load data in that format and trying to work with it in Hive with the "correct" data types, you could populate `cust_staging` as you would normally have loaded the table and then populate your target table `cust` with a CTAS statement like:

```
CREATE TABLE cust AS SELECT
  CAST(event AS INT) AS event,
  CAST(pid AS INT) AS pid,
  CAST(REQ_FROM_IP AS INT) AS REQ_FROM_IP,
  CAST(REQ_CITY_ID AS INT) AS REQ_CITY_ID,
  CAST(REQ_STATE_ID AS INT) AS REQ_STATE_ID,
  CAST(REQ_COUNTRY_ID AS INT) AS REQ_COUNTRY_ID,
  key
FROM cust_staging;
```

And now `cust` will have the column types you were expecting:

```
hive> DESCRIBE cust;
OK
event                       int                                 
pid                         int                                 
req_from_ip                 int                                 
req_city_id                 int                                 
req_state_id                int                                 
req_country_id              int                                 
key                         string                              
Time taken: 0.546 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)
```

Per the excellent input from @JeremyBeard, if you are okay with never materializing the data with it's "correct" types, `cust` can actually be a view:

```
CREATE VIEW `cust` -- All the other stuff is the same
```

To further drill open this line of reasoning, if your use-case is entirely read-only (you never have to actually modify this data), you could define `cust_staging` as an external table (which still uses the OpenCSVSerde) that points to your pipe-separated data files, and then define `cust` as a view into this external table.

However, if your use case is that you need store a table with non-string columns in the OpenCSVSerde format, then you can still create the `cust_staging` table (again, with the same definition you originally had) and populate data in the reverse direction:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE cust_staging SELECT * FROM cust;
```

And if all of that still feels not quite elegant enough (understandable) - the solution may be to extend the OpenCSVSerde into a custom SerDe that will do what you want it to do without the need for intermediary staging tables.

Comment: A variation on this is to convert that CTAS to a view so that the data can be read from the original files without a pre-conversion step.

Comment: @JeremyBeard +1 Thanks and well-spotted - I've added discussion of that into the answer, as well yet another variation implementing a view into an external table in the event the use case is purely read-only.

Comment: @rchang, JeremyBeard Thank you for the help. However I just did numerical operations on the numbers represented as strings. (Did sum of req_state_id. Although not logical but just for testing ). I found it ran perfectly fine which establish that Hive query runner is weakly typed. So, is there any need for me to use actual types when I can do same operations on number strings?

Comment: Creating two tables means double storage which is not affordable particularly with Hive working with Big Data. I think it would be better for me to extend OpenCsv SerDe.

Comment: @CTRL-ALT-DELETE The SerDe extension approach is probably the cleanest in the long run, so I agree with you on that.  With respect for just ingesting data as strings and letting the Hive runtime dynamically cast things, that too is a valid approach as long as you are confident about quality of the incoming data (you won't have non-numeric data where you expect integers, for example).